# what is the difference between DPAPI and file.encrypt

Tags: vb.net, winforms, encryption

what is the difference between DPAPI and file.encrypt (I/O)??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File.Encrypt calls [EncryptFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364021(VS.85).aspx) that uses the [Encrypting File System](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364021(VS.85).aspx) which in turn uses the [DPAPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Protection_API) to protect the encryption keys.  Basically, File.Encrypt is one of many potential encryption schemes that utilize the key management capabilities provided by [Windows Data Protection (DPAPI) Architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995355.aspx).